# How to calculate the total size of attachments in a SharePoint form

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2013, attachment

We have a form where the total size of attachments the users can add must be limited. We are trying to achieve this by adding up the size of attachments with the code below. It does work for NEW FORMS, but on EDIT FORMS, this code cannot find the attachments.
In particular, when e.g. filepath has the value  of 'attachment.txt', the following line returns a 'File not found' error:

```
var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
```

Any suggestions please?

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PreSaveAction() {
            var Check;
            var size = 0;
            $('#idAttachmentsTable').find('tr').each(function () {
                var filepath = $(this).find('span[dir="ltr"]').text();                
                var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");                
                var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath); // <-- this line gives a 'File not found' error for EDIT FORMS
                size = size + thefile.size;
                   })

                if (size > 500 * 1024) 
                  { //500kb for test purpose

                    alert('The file size is greater than 500 kb. Please reduce the file size.');
                    return false;
                  } 
                else
                  {                    
                    Check = true;
                  }            

            return Check;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was curious if this pre check might help / does it return results ?

```
if($('tr #idAttachmentsRow').attr('style').length)
{
// There are attachments
}
else
{
// No attachments found.
}
```

Comment: We got the following, on an edit form (note that the code above run when clicked on the Save button of the form):
1) If there were no attachments, and we added a new, to code above incorrectly showed "no attachments"
2) If we opened a form with existing attachments, it correctly showed that there were attachments.
3) If we deleted all attachments from a form, it incorrectly showed that there were attachments